# Import a module in python as a command line option

Tags: python, debugging, command-line-interface

Is there a way to import a module through the command line, that gets exposed to the running script (or ideally through all execution)?
My use case is to debug: I have a set of debugging utils (to display images, histograms...) that I only want to import while debugging (and that other people on my team do not need to care about, the debugging code doesn't get pushed to the main repo, it doesn't get imported at execution time...).

For example, when debugging on my end, I would like to do: `python --option "import debug_utils.py" main.py`, and my personal debugging functionalities would be visible to the running scripts.

At execution time others and me would simply execute, without package/import conflicts:
`python main.py`, and the debugging utils are not imported.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option to Python, but you could gate the import of your debugging utilities using an environment variable, like this:

```py
import os

if 'MY_APP_DEBUG' in os.environ:
    import debug_utils
else:
    debug_utils = None
```

And then in your code, you can write:

```py
if debug_utils is not None:
    debug_utils.show_debugging_data()
```